# Array gets modified if another one does

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

It's really strange, I'm modifying one of the arrays and the other one gets modified! I found no way of making it work other than typing two times the array. What can I do?

```
function test(a,b,c,d)
{
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
    this.c=c;
    this.d=d;
}

var data0=data=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];

function construct(constructor,args)
{
    function F(){return constructor.apply(this,args);}
    F.prototype=constructor.prototype;
    return new F();
}

for(var i=0,l=data.length;i<l;i++)
{
    data[i]=construct(test,data[i]);
}

console.log(data0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/3GNMC/2/

Comment: data0 and data are the same array. Use `data0 = data.slice(0);` to clone

Comment: You are not creating separate copies of your array, instead creating separate references to the same array.  Search the site for how to clone/copy an array and you will find your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the same items:

```
var data0=data=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];
```

(and as a side note - here `data` ends up on the global object as it isn't really declared, only `data0` is)

If you want to generate two different arrays with identical items you can do this:

```
var data0 =[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];
var data = [];

data = data.concat(data0);
```

or

```
 data = data0.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will not copy arrays upon `data0=data` assignment, instead it will point both variables to the same object in memory. You need to actually *clone* the array fully, for example:

```
var data0 = data.slice(0);
```